# Interpolations-called, even if ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

Tags: angular, performance

For my project I have to create a table with many rows (> 1000), which doesn't perform well. To demonstrate the problem, I've created a simple application, which contains a collapsable div and mutiple divs, which are created via *ngFor.

There is only one component (the app.component generated by the angular CLI).

The html-file looks like this:

```
<div style="border:1px solid silver" (click)="toggleDiv()">TEST</div>

<div #divToToggle [ngStyle]="divStyle">
</div>


<div *ngFor="let row of rows">{{getName(row)}}</div>
```

The Component-Class creates 100 objects with a property called name. The Method getName called in the template logs the call to the console and returns the name property.

The class also provides a method used to expand/collapse the collapsable div.

When a I click on the TEST-div, the method toggleDiv() is executed. And: each time this method is called, the method getName() for all rows is called.

IMHO this is completely unneccessary and creates performance issues (with css-animations etc.).

Since the component uses ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, I don't understand, why angular executes all these interpolations, even if nothing changes!

Does anybody have an idea, how to change this behaviour? I would like angular to render the table and than do absolutely nothing unless any input-parameter of the component changes.

Angular-Versions tried:  4.4.4 and 5.1.3

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {

  rows: any[];

  expanded = false;
  divStyle: any;

  expandedStyle = {
    "height": "200px",
    "background-color": "orange"
  }
  collapsedStyle = {
    "display": "none"
  }

  constructor() {
    this.divStyle = this.expandedStyle;
    this.expanded = true;
    this.rows = this.createRows(100);
  }

  toggleDiv() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    if (this.expanded) {
      this.divStyle = this.expandedStyle;
    } else {
      this.divStyle = this.collapsedStyle;
    }    
  }

  getName(row:any): string {
    console.log("getName called")
    return row.name;
  }

  private createRows(count:number): any[] {
    let rows: any[] = [];

    for (let i=0; i < count; i++) {
      rows.push({
        name: "TEST " + (i+1)
      })
    }
    return rows;
  }
}
```

The angular-CLI project can be found at [DropBox][1]

Comment: BTW: since the component uses ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, I am suprised, that toggling the div works properly (no input-parameter of the app.component is changed but the div is re-rendered properly).


I don't want to use virtual scrolling, because that causes other problems (e.g. different heights of table-rows etc.)

Comment: Events received by the component also causes change detection to run, not only `@Input()`s. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bind to a function, bind to a property instead

```
{{getName(row)}}
```

should be

```
{{getName[row]}}
```

where `getName` is an array field that contains the pre-calculated values for each row.

`OnPush` does run change detection when an `@Input()` was updated or an event handler in the component received an event (`(click)="...")` or when an `|async` pipe receives an event.

`OnPush` just skips change detection for the component when the parent component runs change detection.

You can also detach the change detector of the current component to avoid change detection more strictly that `OnPush` itself does.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Now I've tried the following:

- ngAfterViewInit:  changeDetectorRef.detach()
- use Renderer2 to change the style of the collapsable 

=> now it works as expected

This means: execute change-detection manually, when the rows-property changes (using a setter)

Comment: You can also `attach(), update the bound value, call `detectChanges()`, and `detach()` again. Accessing the DOM imperatively is ugly in Angular.